# Query about fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm very new to Solr and I'm looking at someone else's code. I'm looking at the schema.xml and found the following:

1. `field`
2. `dynamicfield`
3. `copyField`

What is the difference between these please?

Thanks! :)

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all thoroughly explained in the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml).

Also [here's a blogpost](http://www.tnrglobal.com/blog/2010/07/dynamic-fields-in-apache-solr/) about dynamicFields, and [here's another one about copyFields](http://www.liquidfoot.com/2007/10/05/solr-schema/), they might help.